# "React: 'Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop' warning in my component hierarchy"

Tags: reactjs

I'm encountering a warning in my React application, and I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving it. The warning message states:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I've reviewed my code and made sure that I'm providing a unique key prop in my component where I'm mapping over an array, but the warning still persists. Here's the relevant code structure:

This is the error:

[image]

This is my Home.js file

[image]
This is my MealDetails.js file

[image]

I've confirmed that the `meal._id` values are unique within the meals array, and I'm using them as keys when rendering MealDetails components. However, I'm still receiving the warning.

Here are some additional details that might help diagnose the issue:

- I've checked other components and haven't found any issues with key assignment.
- The error doesn't seem to originate from the MealDetails component itself.
- I've reviewed my context and reducer code (provided in another question), and it appears to be correctly set up.

Any insights into what might be causing this warning and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The code needs to be in the question.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Try to write code snippet. @Shezi

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign unique key value in `map()` of the array.
If you have a unique key in each element of array, you can that one. But if not, you can use `index` of map.

```js
{ meals.map((meal, idx) => <MealDetails meal={meal} key={idx} />) }
```

or

```
{ meals.map(meal => <MealDetails meal={meal} key={meal._id} />) }
```

But you have done. You need to check `meal._id`s are unique.

```js
{ meals.map(meal => {
  console.log(meal._id);
  return <MealDetails meal={meal} key={meal._id} /> 
  })
}
```

You can check the results on the console of web browser. If the same _ids are exists or _id is undefined, rewrite the meals collection.
thanks.

Comment: Induces are not good key values if the collection will change. But OP already states they have an id, and it’s being supplied as the key property already.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built in `index` argument in the `map()` function. More info can be found [in the docs](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key)

As a test, I would try updating your code to add the map method's index argument and pass it in as a key prop of the top level JSX element, like so:

```
{meals &&
   meals.map((meal, index) => {
   return <MealDetails meal={meal} key={index} />;
})}
```

Comment: Array indices are generally not a good idea if the array will be modified.